# integrating watson chatbot with chatbase

Tags: watson, chatbase

I a beginner with IBM watson. I know that we can integrate bot build in dialogflow/ API/AI with chatbase and both are the services provided by google. I need a clarification on whether I can integrate it with the bot created using watson.

I have implemented a twitter bot in watson, I used NodeJs and the package watson-developer-cloud from https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud. For chatbase I found a package called @google/chatbase.
I want to integrate my twitter bot with chatbase(if possible). Hope somebody can direct me in doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Chatbase integrates with any type of bot (voice or text), built on any platform, via the Chatbase API. See this quickstart: https://chatbase.com/documentation/quickstart#documentation